# Disabling join on CakePHP find function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Is there an easy way to disable the join for a find query in CakePHP

I have a `Product` model object that has a `$belongsTo` relation to User.
My find query is:

```
$product = $this->Product->find('first',array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Product.name'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Product.active'=>1,
    ),

    'recursive' => false
));
```

The sql query that gets executes looks like this:

```
SELECT `Product`.`name` FROM `db`.`products` AS `Product` LEFT JOIN `db`.`users` AS `Owner` ON (`Product`.`owner_id` = `Owner`.`id`) LIMIT 1
```

Now I want to get rid of the join with `users` for performance reasons and since I don't use the data. Is there an easy way to do this? I hoped disabling recursive and manually setting the field argument would do the trick.

Comment: Try recursive = -1.  The book doesn't say anything about false.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best practice (imo) to set `public $recursive = -1;` in your AppModel.  This will get rid of the auto-magic finding that goes on, and will also allow you to use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) whenever you need additional data without having to set recursive to -1 all over the place.

I believe in CakePHP 3+, they're going to get rid of recursive and make Containable on by default (just what I've heard - I haven't verified).

(If you REALLY don't want to set it everywhere, you can just set it immediately before the find - but... better to just set it in the AppModel and NEVER change it back)